# Change left column in the agenda day of Full calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, fullcalendar

I need to change left column of agenda day, where hours are placed (12am, 1am, 2am etc) to just counters.

Instead of 12am there should be 1; instead of 1am, 2; instead of 2am, 3 etc.

How can i do this ?

[image: Here I attached image]

Comment: The best thing to do this is, edit the plugin. I too needed some features related to this, then i edited my plugin code, now it's working fine.

Comment: Yes , i have edited plugin and it works . thank you )

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the first column of a table maybe? Try

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var rows = 0;
    $('tr').each(function() {
        if (rows > 1)
        {
            var cell = $(this).find('td:first');
            var val = cell.html();
            cell.html(val.substring(0,val.length-3));
        }
        rows++;
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a working solution. Add this code to the viewRender property/function:

```
viewRender: function(view){
    if(view.type !== 'agendaDay') return;
    var timeSpans = document.querySelectorAll('.fc-axis.fc-time > span');
    for(var i = 0; i < timeSpans.length; i++){
        timeSpans[i].innerHTML = i + 1;
    }
}
```